# How to create a window function that can update model data in a rendered VueJS v3 app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a use case that requires me to use window level vanilla JavaScript functions to be able to refresh/update data inside of an already rendered Vue app. I can't really use any async processes or triggers from inside of Vue itself since essentially this app will be running inside of something similar to an iframe.

I've followed Vue's getting started guide, and while I am able to make my simple table render with default data, I can not get functions to work when calling from outside Vue. I use tailwind, and vite-single-file to compile this into a single page code file (all which is working).

What I am expecting to do is run a function to pass some JSON in the window, ***refreshData(json) ***, then have the performRefresh function from App.vue update the model data from the provided data.

The code I've tried seems simple:

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Test App</title>
    <script>
      function refreshData(newData) {
        app.performRefresh(newData);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="m-0 p-0">
    <div id="app" class="w-full"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### main.ts

```
import './assets/main.css'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
const app = createApp(App)
window.app = app;
app.mount('#app')
```

### App.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import data from './assets/defaultData.json'
  const tableData = ref(data)

  const performRefresh = (newData) => {
    console.log("Test Reactivity Function");
    tableData.test = newData;
  }

  window.performRefresh = performRefresh;
</script>

<template>
  <div class="px-4">
    <table class="w-full">
      <tr v-for="row in tableData.test">
# Standard model rendering with mustaches here
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <h1>TEST VALUE: {{ tableData.test }}</h1>
</template>
```

I've tried a number of different approaches, all with varying results of failure. Mostly suggestions from reading other similar topics on StackOverflow, the Vue3 documentation and online.

1. Setup a watch() in vue in a hidden  to watch a field's value changing, then using js in the refreshData() function to stick the newData into the hidden field. This does not work (but did work if I manually copied and pasted JSON data to the field).
2. Try to use Pinia to setup a store (everything worked inside of vue, but was not accessible or targetable from the window level).
3. Use Mitt to attempt a different store approach with the same issue as Pinia. Could get Mitt running at the window level and vue level, but with different stores that would not talk to each other. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mitt
4. Trying to use Vue Events to watch the window DOM, but the event would never fire.

I feel like I'm missing something basic and obvious here, but can't quite connect the pieces. Thanks for taking the time to make recommendations to a novice Vue user.

Answer (score 0):

Just assigning the function to `window` should work. But note that your `performRefresh()` is not writing the ref's value, but a self-defined property `test`, which won't be reactive and can't be used in the template. Looking at the template, I think you want to do

```
tableData.value.test = newData;
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const App = {
  template: `
    <h6>Inside Vue:</h6>
    <pre>{{data.test}}</pre>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in data.test">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
  setup() {
    const data = ref({test: [1,2,3]})
    const setTest = (test) => data.value.test = test
    window.setTest = setTest
    return {data, setTest}
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')

function setRandomList(){
  const rnd = (max) => 1+Math.random() * max|0
  const list = Array.from({length: rnd(7)}, () => rnd(100))
  window.setTest(list)
}
```

```css
.panel{
  border: 1px solid black; 
  padding: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <h6>Outside Vue:</h6>
  <button onclick="setRandomList()">Update List</button>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="app">

</div>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I went down the path of using defineExpose() previously as well.

I am able to get it work while under `npm run dev` in my local browser. However, when I compile it with vite-single-app into a single file, it no longer works, and the console error returned is:
`index.html:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'exposed')
    at logTest (index.html:41:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:56:49)`

Most likely this is an issue with vite, so I will investigate that. But at least it is progress. Thanks!

Comment: The plugin I'm referencing is vite-plugin-singlefile: https://github.com/richardtallent/vite-plugin-singlefile

Comment: Oh crap, you are right, `app._instance` is not available in prod build. That leaves adding the function to window, which should work. I think the problem is in `performRefresh()`, have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: The `<template>` section of my code is overly simplified, the `tableData` is an array of objects, with many drilled down bits of data. I will need the model to be reactive so vue can re-draw the components when tableData is changed, and there's a two-way component where Vue's @blur runs a lazy-save function to send data back to the parent app. All of that is already working but was omitted to keep the code simple for debugging.

Comment: What I mean is that in the code in the question, `performRefresh()` assigns to `tableData.test = newData;`, but since `tabelData` is a ref, it has to be `tableData.value.test = newData;`. Is this just an error in the question?

Comment: Thank you, I've add `window.performRefresh = performRefresh` in App.vue to bind the function, I update `refreshData()` in index.html to use `window.performRefresh()`. I'm still testing but at a glance this seems to work.

Comment: `v-for` updates automatically, it is not necessary (or possible) to trigger an update manually.I have added a snippet to the answer where you can see it working as expected. If that does not help, it is probably best if you could add a similar snippet to your question where the error can be observed